# Number of 'good words' that can be formed?

Tags: combinations

> A “good” word is any seven letter word consisting of letters from
>   {A,B,C} (some letters may be absent and some letter can be present
>   more than once), with the restriction that A cannot be followed by B,
>   B cannot be followed by C, and C cannot be followed by A. How many
>   good words are there?

This question has already been answered here: [How many good words are there?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736358/how-many-good-words-are-there)

BUT i have doubts regarding the solution:

> You can choose the first letter in 3 ways and any of the other letters
>   in 2 ways, so there can be **3∗$2^6$=192** good words

**The remaining six letters can be chosen in 6 ways each?** But if we choose **A** at first place , then we can have **A's** following it , but once we put a '**C**' in some position, it can't be followed by any more **A's** because **"C cannot be followed by A"**!

So, once we stumble upon a '**C**' , we have only **1** possible letter for the remaining positions- which is "**C**".

I hope i made myself clear, any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer interprets followed by as meaning immediately followed by.  It would allow ACBACBA as a good word because none of the restrictions are violated.  I agree with that reading of the problem.

Comment: OH!!! Well, thank you so much.